# Export HAR file in Android WebView

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, google-chrome-devtools, har

Is it possible to record a HAR file in an Android WebView or Chrome for Android without using Chrome Remote Debugging?

Background: I'm trying to troubleshoot some network related issues that some users experience around the world. As the users do not have IT knowledge/experience, connecting the phone to the computer in order to use Chrome Remote Debugging is not an option.

So I need to export the HAR on the device itself. All the tutorials on how to create a HAR file use either the DevTools or some kind of automation/testing software (such as selenium).